I am facing an issue with Docker URL and ENV
I am using AWS code build to perform CI for a python application, where I believe I configured the environment variables correctly in the parameters store and build spec script.
Please take a look at the logs and let me know what's wrong. I tried troubleshooting the obvious methods but none seem to be working.
[Container] 2024/10/27 16:54:16.033234 Running command docker build -t "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME/python-flask-app:latest" .
ERROR: invalid tag "***/***/python-flask-app:latest": invalid reference format

[Container] 2024/10/27 16:54:16.169155 Command did not exit successfully docker build -t "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME/python-flask-app:latest" . exit status 1
[Container] 2024/10/27 16:54:16.174815 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/10/27 16:54:16.174835 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker build -t "$DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL/$DOCKER_REGISTRY_USERNAME/python-flask-app:latest" .. Reason: exit status 1

Where, the *** in the second line of the log is the original output as I did not redact it to not show the sensitive info.
Also, what URL would you include in the parameter store for docker hub to push the artifact?
I tried checking for ENV typos, etc but none seem to be working
